# Uploading mp4 to Heroku -- file is not saved

Tags: python, heroku, upload, mp4

I'm trying to upload a .mp4 video to be processed by Python server in Heroku. In my server.py, I've have following code:

```
# Initialize the Flask application
MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'] = 'uploads'
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

# route http posts to this method
@app.route('/api/uploadFile', methods=['POST'])
def uploadFile():
    r = request # this is the incoming request        
    uploaded_file = r.files['uploadedfile']
    # save the incoming video file locally
    if uploaded_file.filename != '':        
        content = r.files['uploadedfile'].read()        
        uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(MYDIR, uploaded_file.filename))
```

However, when I run `heroku run bash` and do `ls` I don't see the file at all. I've looked at the previous posts regarding this and doing what many have suggested, i.e., to have an absolute path `os.path.join(MYDIR, uploaded_file.filename)`. But I still don't see the file. I know that Heroku is an ephemeral system and doesn't store files, but all I want to do is process the video file and after it's done, I'll myself delete it. Oh by the way, the video is approx 25MB in size. I tried a low quality version which is around 4MB and the problem still persists, so my guess is it is not the size of the video that's the problem.

Also, when I read the content via `content = r.files['uploadedfile'].read()`, I do see that `content` is approximately of length 25M suggesting that I'm indeed receiving the video correctly.

Ideally, I would love to convert the byte stream to something like list of frames and then process it using opencv. But I thought, I can, as a first step, just save it locally, then read and process. I don't care that it is deleted after 5 minutes of my processing is done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Banged my head around for a day looking for a solution. Thanks!!!

Just want to add that the commands above give me no error. So it seems like everything worked but then when I do heroku run bash, I see no file anywhere. It would've been great if there was an error or an warning provided by the system :-(.

Also, I tried running things locally on localhost server and it does store the file. So it works locally on my machine, just can't seem to save it in Heroku.

Comment: _"I do see that `content` is approximately of length 25M"_ Is it not possible to save `content` itself as a file (since it holds the video bytes due to `.read`)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already tried that with the following piece of code to convert from bytes: 
`with open(os.path.join(MYDIR, uploaded_file.filename), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(b64decode(content))
`
But that also doesn't work. Even temporarily. I've used Heroku in the past where I have done ```cv2.imwrite('image.jpeg', img)``` and that does save it temporarily inside the /app folder. But somehow, I'm not able to store the .mp4 video. Quite frustrating.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured out what was going on. Like a duffer, I had read the file first (content = ...) and then saved it. This took the file pointer to the end of file and hence it was not saving anything. So I removed that line. Secondly, when I was doing heroku run bash to check if the file exists, it was getting removed since a new dyno was restarted and it removed that file. Now it's working!!